# ExtJS Panel Layout: how to correctly layout Panels

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am trying to render an [Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel) A that takes the whole horizontal space. Then I'm trying to render two panels, B and C, underneath Panel A, both taking 50% of the horizontal space.

Therefore, I want to achieve is this structure:

```
-------------
|     A     |
-------------
|  B  |  C  |
-------------
```

But as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvzammit/9VMRm/3/) I'm achieving the following panel rendering:

```
-------------
|     A     |
-------------
|     B     |
-------------
|     C     |
-------------
```

Please feel free to fork the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvzammit/9VMRm/3/) to achieve the alignment I need as described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about have a view  like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    padding: 10,
    layout: {
        align: 'stretch',
        pack: 'center',
        type: 'vbox'
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    flex: 1,
                    height: 150,
                    title: 'A'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    flex: 1,
                    height: 150,
                    layout: {
                        padding: '10 0 10 0',
                        align: 'stretch',
                        type: 'hbox'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            flex: 1,
                            width: 150,
                            title: 'B'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            flex: 1,
                            width: 150,
                            title: 'C'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Only comment I would make is that padding really belongs on the component as opposed to the layout. It's likely something that will be phased out over time.